# excel vba merging contents of csv files to a new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

The below code gets all csv files in a folder and merges its content into the Master File

```
Sub Consolidate()
    Dim path As String, ThisWB As String, lngFilecounter As Long
    Dim wbDest As Workbook, shtDest As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet
    Dim Filename As String, Wkb As Workbook
    Dim CopyRng As Range, Dest As Range
    Dim RowofCopySheet As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long, lngDstLastRow As Long, lngLastCol As Long, i As Integer
Dim wksDst As Worksheet
Set wksDst = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("QA Master")


lngDstLastRow = LastOccupiedRowNumInCol(wksDst, 1)
lastrow = Worksheets("QA Master").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lngLastCol = LastOccupiedColNumInRow(wksDst, 1)
'clears previous contents along with formatting

    If lngDstLastRow > 1 Then
        With wksDst
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngDstLastRow, lngLastCol)).ClearContents
            .Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lngDstLastRow, lngLastCol)).ClearFormats
        End With
    End If


    RowofCopySheet = 2 ' Row to start on in the sheets you are copying from

    ThisWB = ActiveWorkbook.Name

    path = "Path to folder"

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set shtDest = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Filename = Dir(path & "\*.csv", vbNormal)
    If Len(Filename) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    Do Until Filename = vbNullString
        If Not Filename = ThisWB Then
            Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=path & "\" & Filename)
            Set CopyRng = Wkb.Sheets(1).Range(Cells(RowofCopySheet, 1), Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
            Set Dest = shtDest.Range("A" & shtDest.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1)
            CopyRng.Copy Dest
            Wkb.Close False
        End If
        
        Filename = Dir()
    Loop

    Range("A1").Select

    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ThisWorkbook.Save
    MsgBox "Update Done!"
End Sub
Public Function LastOccupiedRowNumInCol(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                                        ColNum As Long) As Long
    Dim lng
    If ColNum > 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells(.Rows.Count, ColNum).End(xlUp).Row
        End With
    Else
        lng = 0
    End If
    LastOccupiedRowNumInCol = lng
End Function

Public Function LastOccupiedColNumInRow(Sheet As Worksheet, _
                                        RowNum As Long) As Long
    Dim lng As Long
    If RowNum > 0 Then
        With Sheet
            lng = .Cells(RowNum, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        End With
    Else
        lng = 0
    End If
    LastOccupiedColNumInRow = lng
End Function
```

Everything works as expected except the date column, the format for some of the dates is changed (mm/dd/yy instead of original dd/mm/yy) I tried NumberFormat but it is not helpful.
The rest of the code works perfectly fine. The only issue is some of the date format gets changed. The date entered in the csv file is of uniform date type (dd/mm/yy). How is it possible that only some of the date gets changed? Any insights is appreciated.Thanks

[Excel data sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDp8H.png)

Comment: If your short date format is `mm/dd/yyyy` it will try to convert the `dd/mm/yyyy` as if it is `mm/dd/yyyy` which means as long as the first set of numbers is less than 12 it assumes that is the month not the day and converts it that way.  so `12/05/2021` will convert as the 5th of Dec not the 12th of May.  Any that have the first group greater than 12 will not convert and come in as text.  see [HERE](https://www.reddit.com/r/excelevator/comments/5ncbz1/vba_macro_import_csv_and_specify_column_data_types/) for an example how to import and set the format correctly.

Comment: Hi @ScottCraner I just observed this less than 12 is getting converted, thanks for the link, will go through it

Comment: Hi@ScottCraner I just went through the code, How can I implement xlTextFormat in my code though

Comment: You can't you have to import not open the file.  Once the file is opened it will cause the issue.  The only way with your current code is to get the supplier of the csv to use a standard universal format of `yyyy-mm-dd` which all systems will recognize and be able to convert.  short of that you can try.  [workbook.opentext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.opentext) which will allow you to set the format as it is imported.

Comment: @ScottCraner It's not really clear in the documentation but the `Workbook.OpenText` won't work to set the column as Text if the file type is `.csv`.  One can change the extension to `.txt`, or copy the `csv` with a destination file extension of `txt`

Comment: Still not able to find a fix for this. I will keep trying though